# Integrating ZXing for Glass Release into Android Studio project

Tags: zxing, google-glass

I'm working on QR Code scanning on Google glass. I've used ZXing in android and was happy to find a google glass port has been released recently.

I've downloaded and installed the APK on glass and it works great. However I am having trouble incorporating the project into my own project. There is no maven resource and I've tried importing it as a module without success.

I've also tried incorporating the code into my project, however I get a range of compilation errors such as:

Error:(109, 43) type parameter com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType is not within its bound
Error:(163, 44) cannot find symbol method decode(com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap,java.util.Map).

Here is a link to the provided release - https://github.com/zxing/zxing/releases/tag/BSGlass-0.2.1 - does anyone have any suggestions on how to make an app like the sample one using the provided code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this "Intent" in your activity to start the QR scanner (ZXing) on your Google Glass:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); 
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); 
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

You have to then handle the results returned by the scan.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Card card = new Card(this);
            card.setText(contents); 
            View cardView = card.getView();
            setContentView(cardView);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to make changes to your AndroidManifest.xml

This blog does a good job at explaining what you need to do -> http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/does